# ParseLong raise NumberFormatException

Tags: java, hadoop

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
```

Relevant segment of code:

```
  public static class NodeWritable implements Writable {

    public double msg;
    public double rank;
    public String others;

    public NodeWritable(double msg, double rank, String others) {
      this.msg = msg;
      this.rank = rank;
      this.others = others;
    }

    public NodeWritable() {
      this.msg = 0.0;
      this.rank = 0.0;
      this.others = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
      out.writeDouble(msg);
      out.writeDouble(rank);
      out.writeChars(others + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
      msg = in.readDouble();
      rank = in.readDouble();
      others = in.readLine();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "" + rank;
    }
  }


  ArrayList<Long> incoming_vids = new ArrayList<Long>();
  for (NodeWritable msg : messages) {
    String in_vid = msg.others.trim();
    incoming_vids.add(Long.parseLong(in_vid));
  }
```

How can this happen? I've done some research with Google. Sometime `NumberFormatException` seems to be caused by big numbers. But I just can't find a possible explanation for my case.

Comment: `Long.parseLong("10");` works for me. Please provide the actual code, not just the exception.

Comment: can u give the sample code which you have used

Comment: One possibility is a non-printing character in the input string. NumberFormatException is about **any** way in which the input string is not a properly formatted representation of a number in the type being parsed, not just about big input.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan Sounds possible. How do I trim those invisible characters? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop on the string in_vid and check if any character is other than digit using this

```
    for(int i=0;i<in_vid.length();i++) {
            char ch = in_vid.charAt(i);
       if( Character.isDigit(ch)) {
//   do something
}
    }
```

if its other than digit then you can eliminate it in the loop and pass only the string which has digits.

Answer (score 0):

This is really an extended comment, not an answer. My hypothesis is that the problem is a non-printing character in the input string. It could be tested by changing the code to:

```
  for (NodeWritable msg : messages) {
    String in_vid = msg.others.trim();
    try{
       incoming_vids.add(Long.parseLong(in_vid));
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      for(char c : in_vid.toCharArray()){
        System.out.println("0x"+Integer.toHexString(c));
      }
    }
  }
```

This code should cause a character-by-character hex printout of the input string.

If it is an embedded non-printing character, you should probably be rejecting the string, and fixing it at its origin.